# How to implement a virtual function in derived class?

Tags: c++, virtual

Consider the following UML:

[image: UML for 4 classes]

When I try to implement the virtual function `rate()` in `Single.cpp`, I get an error:  cannot allocate an object of abstract type 'Single'
Booking* b = new Single();

[image: image of the error I'm getting]

The `addBooking()` function should make a pointer of `Single` of type `Booking`, add the pointer to the `QList` (`BookingList` derives from `QList<Booking*>`) and return the `Booking` pointer.

When I comment out the virtual function then everything works.  Why is this occurring, and how can I fix it?

Below is a minimal version of my program:

```cpp
#ifndef BOOKING_H
#define BOOKING_H

class Booking
{
public:
    Booking();
    double SINGLE_PPPN = 200.00;
    virtual double rate() = 0;
};

#endif // BOOKING_H
```

```cpp
#include "booking.h"

Booking::Booking()
{
}
```

```cpp
#ifndef BOOKINGLIST_H
#define BOOKINGLIST_H
#include <QList>
#include <iostream>
#include "booking.h"
#include "single.h"

using namespace std;

class BookingList : public QList<Booking*>
{
public:
    BookingList();
    Booking* addBooking();
    void deleteAll();
};

#endif // BOOKINGLIST_H
```

```cpp
#include "bookinglist.h"

BookingList::BookingList()
{
}

Booking* BookingList::addBooking()
{
    Booking* b = new Single();

    this->append(b);

    cout << "Total bookings: " << this->size() << "\n\n" <<endl;

    return b;
}

void BookingList::deleteAll()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < this->count(); i++)
    {
        cout << "Deleting Item At: " << i << endl;
        delete this->at(i);
    }
}
```

```cpp
#ifndef SINGLE_H
#define SINGLE_H
#include "booking.h"

class Single : public Booking
{
public:
    Single();
};

#endif // SINGLE_H
```

```cpp
#include "single.h"

Single::Single()
{
}

double Single::rate()
{
    return Booking::SINGLE_PPPN;
}
```

```cpp
#include <QCoreApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: You need to declare `rate` as part of the class declaration (in the header) - otherwise the compiler can't know you will be implementing that function

Comment: you should add overrided function "rate()" declaration to "single.h" header

Comment: Please add the error message as text to your question so that the next person with the same error can find this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare your method `override` in the class definition

```
class Single : public Booking
{
public:
    Single();
    double rate() override;  // this line
};
```

then you can actually implement the method in your cpp file as you did

```
double Single::rate()
{
    return Booking::SINGLE_PPPN;
}
```

Comment: The `override` specifier is good practice (at least, since C++11) but technically optional.    The minimum requirement is that the function be declared in the derived class with the same argument types, return type, and a compatible exception specification.   The `override` specifier helps catch some problems (e.g. if the inherited function is not `virtual` in the base class).

Comment: What is meant by compatible exception specification?

Comment: @ClintTheron it means whether the function is declared `noexcept`

Comment: Booking is the superclass of Single and BookingList append Single pointers, of type Booking, to the QList. In my client I make an instance of BookList and call addBooking which returns a Booking pointer. When I call methods on this Booking pointer I only get the methods of Booking. How do I access the methods of Single through this Booking pointer? Is it even possible? Thanks :)